# How to edit a Maven resources file from Java?

Tags: java, file, maven

If I'm reading in a resources file in Java, creating a temp file, and then using the temp file to store changes, is there a way to write out the modified file to the resource file? Basically, can I replace the resource file in Java?

Comment: What is a *resources file*? What format is the file? What exactly are you doing right now (including file paths!)? In what way is this a maven related question?

Comment: I'm using files located in the "Resources" folder so when I build my project with Maven they are included in the JAR file. The file I am looking to edit/replace is a text file. Right now I am accessing the file via `InputStream is = (this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("users.txt")`. The file is located at the top level of the Resources folder. I am wondering if it is possible to modify or add/delete files that are packaged as resources with Maven

Comment: The whole idea of those resources is that they are static and can (only) be accessed via the classloader. If you need to modify them, use them only for default values, copy the files to writeable storage, and then access them from there.